# How to test mongoose in NestJS Service?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I would like to test `getFund()` method from my service. I use NestJS that uses jest by default. 
I have no idea how to test this line with jest: `return await this.fundModel.findById(id);`. Any idea?

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Fund } from '../../funds/interfaces/fund.interface';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';


@Injectable()
export class FundService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Fund')
    private readonly fundModel: Model<Fund>,
  ) {}

  /*****
    SOME MORE CODE
  ****/

  async getFund(id: string): Promise<Fund> {
    return await this.fundModel.findById(id);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Thanks to slideshowp2 answer, I wrote this test.

```
describe('#getFund', () => {
    it('should return a Promise of Fund', async () => {
      let spy = jest.spyOn(service, 'getFund').mockImplementation(async () => {
        return await Promise.resolve(FundMock as Fund);
      });
      service.getFund('');
      expect(service.getFund).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(await service.getFund('')).toEqual(FundMock);
      spy.mockRestore();
    });
  });
```

The problem is that I get this result in my coverage report:

[image: statement not covered]

When I hover the line I get `statement not covered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one statement `return await this.fundModel.findById(id);` in your `getFund` method. There is no other code logic which means the unit test you can do is only mock `this.fundModel.findById(id)` method and test 
 it `.toBeCalledWith(someId)`.

We should mock each method and test the code logic in your `getFund` method. For now, there is no other code logic.

For example

```js
 async getFund(id: string): Promise<Fund> {
    // we should mock this, because we should make an isolate environment for testing `getFund`
    const fundModel = await this.fundModel.findById(id); 
    // Below branch we should test based on your mock value: fundModel
    if(fundModel) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
```

Update

For example:

```js
describe('#findById', () => {
    it('should find ad subscription by id correctly', async () => {
      (mockOpts.adSubscriptionDataSource.findById as jestMock).mockResolvedValueOnce({ adSubscriptionId: 1 });
      const actualValue = await adSubscriptionService.findById(1);
      expect(actualValue).toEqual({ adSubscriptionId: 1 });
      expect(mockOpts.adSubscriptionDataSource.findById).toBeCalledWith(1);
    });
  });
```

The test coverage report:

[image]

Comment: Hi slideshowp2. Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried what you told me but I still get an error in my coverage report. Do you have any idea why and how to solve this?